# How to center an element related to it's above sibling

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a simple form as below picture

[image]

I want to center "Send" button related to the textarea below "Message" label. If I do this with position absolute, relative and custom margins, it looks different and not centered on different resolutions. I'm also using Bootstrap.

My form is inside a parent div;

```
            <div className="my-5 emailform">
              <form className="contact-form">

                ...other elements

                <h3>Message</h3>
                <textarea className="textarea" name="message" />
                <input className="sendbutton" type="submit" value="Send" />
              </form>
            </div>
```

So what I'm trying to accomplish is, I want to put "sendbutton" element below-middle of "textarea" element. So far all of my tries were not succesful. How can I center an element to it's sibling responsively?

Comment: do you use bootstrap ?

Comment: Yes @AhmedElbessfy I do, but I don't know why it doesn't center the button element

Comment: Ok add with 'contact form' classes "d-flex" to display flex and justify-content-center" to center all form content

Comment: well @AhmedElbessfy this actually worked, the below answer also has worked tho. But I liked your answer better, but something weird happened. I've changed the button's classname to "btn btn-primary", when I do this it doesn't place well, but when I overwrite the style by "width: 50%" it actually centers the button very well. Why does it needs "width: 50%" ?

Comment: because "btn btn-primary" has "display: block" style rule so it will take as much space as available AKA the full width or 100% width but with "width:50%" the button won't take the full width so there is space to move the button. A little tip: inspect the element and take a look at the "Styles" tab in the Developer tools, you will see a checkbox for each style rule, try uncheck it and see what is happening and don't worry all of the changes are temporary and will go away on reloading

Comment: @AhmedElbessfy thanks a lot for the information. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```css
   .contact-form{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
            <div class="my-5 emailform">
              <form class="contact-form">

                ...other elements

                <h3>Message</h3>
                <textarea class="textarea" name="message" ></textarea>
                <input class="sendbutton" type="submit" value="Send" />
              </form>
            </div>
```

There are other methods too like you can give display: inline-block to form children and set their width: 100% and use text-align: center on the parent. But this is the safest.

Comment: I've already tried this, this doesn't work at all. Also please mention which classes I should apply this template.

Comment: @GLHF check it now. Is this what you need?

Comment: Yes this one has solved the issue, but I wonder why it didn't center the elements (the button and the textarea) since I'm using Bootstrap already.

Comment: I haven't used bootstrap classes much, only the grid system, but maybe there is a conflict? You are using react as I saw className, but even in react you can't use a single tag for textarea, and you need a closing tag. Maybe that was the issue?